# Javascript - progress bar with muliple images

Tags: javascript

I want to preload a bunch of images and show the progress bar in the same time.

At the moment the code works only with 1 image, here is it:

```
$progress = document.querySelector('#progress');

var url = 'https://placekitten.com/g/2000/2000';

var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.onprogress = onProgress;
request.onload = onComplete;
request.onerror = onError;

function onProgress(event) {
  if (!event.lengthComputable) {
    return;
  }
  var loaded = event.loaded;
  var total = event.total;
  var progress = (loaded / total).toFixed(2);

  $progress.textContent = 'Loading... ' + parseInt(progress * 100) + ' %';

  console.log(progress);
}

function onComplete(event) {
  var $img = document.createElement('img');
  $img.setAttribute('src', url);
  $progress.appendChild($img);
  console.log('complete', url);
}

function onError(event) {
  console.log('error');
}


$progress.addEventListener('click', function() {
  request.open('GET', url, true);
  request.overrideMimeType('text/plain; charset=x-user-defined');
  request.send(null);
});

<div id="progress">Click me to load</div>
```

And here is the jsfiddle to test the code out: https://jsfiddle.net/q5d0osLr/

How can I make it work with more than one image?

Comment: It is not clear what you want to achieve. Do you want to change the images as the progress happens? As I can see, you have only accessing a single image.

Comment: If I have 10 images, I want the progress bar to reach 100% when all the 10 images finished loading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an `array` to store each progress and create a function to load image and record the necessary information for you.

```js
var $progress = document.querySelector('#progress');
var url = 'https://placekitten.com/g/';
var urls = 
          ['https://i.imgur.com/7raUYR2.jpg', 'https://i.imgur.com/i8GSA1b.jpg', 'https://i.imgur.com/jGkaxEZ.jpg',
            'http://i.imgur.com/cuS5DDv.jpg', 'https://i.imgur.com/bl5DOR0.jpg', 'http://i.imgur.com/TuFu2lK.jpg',
            'https://i.imgur.com/qbwarWi.jpg', 'https://i.imgur.com/hJ9Ylph.gif', 'https://i.imgur.com/8KLbDxe.jpg',
             'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/4e/Pleiades_large.jpg/1024px-Pleiades_large.jpg',
           ];

// Store all progress.
var allProgress = [];


var loadImage = function(url) {
  // Get current index.
  var idx = allProgress.length;
  // Push a progress in array.
  allProgress.push(0.0);


  var onProgress = function(evt) {
    if (!evt.lengthComputable) {
      return;
    }
    var loaded = evt.loaded;
    var total = evt.total;
    var progress = (loaded / total);

    allProgress[idx] = progress;
    
    // Calculate the progress by sum then divide.
    var sum = allProgress.reduce(function(sum, val) {
      return sum + val;
    });
    sum /= allProgress.length;
    sum = sum.toFixed(2);

    $progress.textContent = 'Loading... ' + parseInt(sum * 100) + ' %';

    console.log(progress, idx);
  };

  var onComplete = function(evt) {
    var $img = document.createElement('img');
    $img.setAttribute('src', url);
    document.body.appendChild($img);
    console.log('complete', url);
  };

  var onError = function(evt) {
    // You may have to do something with progress.
    console.log('error');
  };
  
  // Move the request in function. So each of them is independent.
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.onprogress = onProgress;
  request.onload = onComplete;
  request.onerror = onError;

  request.open('GET', url, true);
  request.overrideMimeType('text/plain; charset=x-user-defined');
  request.send(null);
};

$progress.addEventListener('click', function() {
  urls.forEach(function(url) {
    loadImage(url);
  });
});
```

```css
img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="progress">Click me to load</div>
```

Comment: How can I load 3 different images?

Comment: In the for-loop , use an array like urls, then pass urls[i] instead of url.

Comment: What about this line? request.open('GET', url, true); 
Shouldn't the script open a new xhr request for every image?

Comment: It'll use the urls[i] you passed in at loadImage(xxx). The xxx can be accessed in the function with name url.

Comment: I tryed like that, but now in the network tab I get canceled on xhr requests, if I have 10 images, the first 9 get canceled and only the last one has ok (200).

Comment: Did all images come from same server?

Comment: You situation seems like that either side restrict the max request amount at the same time.

Comment: @Lachesis Tested for 10 pics, if you request too much from same domain, like the kittenholder, it seems to block some of the request.